# Unrecognized selector sent to instance in UITableViewCell AccessoryView

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm trying to add a plus button to my `UITableViewCell`.

I subclass a StringElement and add an `UIImageView` as my Cell AccessoryView.

To make it touchable, I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` but everytime I try this, I get the same exception.

My GestureRecognizer and the ImageView are declared at class level of the StringElement.
What am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```cs
public class PrioritizeAndAddElement : StringElement
{
    NSAction Plus;
    UITapGestureRecognizer tap;
    UIImageView image;

    public PrioritizeAndAddElement (string caption, NSAction select, NSAction plus) : base(caption, select)
    {
        Plus = plus;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {   
        UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(tv);
        image = new UIImageView(new UIImage("images/app/greenbutton.png"));
        image.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        image.Frame = new RectangleF(cell.Frame.Width - 65, 14, 25, 25);
        cell.AccessoryView = image;
        tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(image, new Selector("tapped"));
        image.AddGestureRecognizer(tap);
        return cell;
    }

    [Export("tapped")]
    public void tapped(UIGestureRecognizer sender){
        if(Plus != null)
            Plus();
    }
}
```

That's all.  I grab the cell and add the Image and Recognizer to it. In this case, nothing happens.

When I add the recognizer to my TableView, I will get the exception.

I added the whole class of my Element.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Please show your code, it's hard to guess where the problem is otherwise.

Comment: What's the full exception text ? Assuming it's about the `tapped` selector could you show us how you implemented it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with

```
tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer(>>>image<<<, new Selector("tapped"));
```

the target of the gesture recognizer is the image, you have defined tapped in the PrioritizeAndAddElement class.  Try something like this instead

```
public class TappableImageView : UIImageView
{
    NSAction Plus;

    public TappableImageView(NSAction plus, UIImage img) : base(img)
    {
        this.Plus = plus;
    }

    [Export("tapped:")]
    public void Tapped(UIGestureRecognizer sender)
    {
        if(Plus != null)
            Plus();
    }
}

...

image = new TappableImageView(new UIImage("images/brushTexture1.png"));
```

Comment: Nice, of Course i had to do that. I didnt realize the correct meaning of this Target. Of Course there must be an information about the "Where to search for the Export". Thanks!